# Problems sending an integer array over a socket

Tags: c++, c, sockets, ubuntu-17.10

I'm sending an integer array from client to server by socket. Like this ;

```
int arr[3] = {5, 4, 1};


send(sock , &arr, 3 , 0);   //sending the votes count
```

and receiving in server like so

```
recv(new_socket, arr1, 3, 0);
```

I'm getting correct value in `arr1[0]` but in `arr1[1]` I'm getting `66` and `arr1[2]` I'm getting `67`

I don't know how this happening and where `66` and `67` is coming from

Comment: That `3` is a *byte count*, not an element count. the two are only synonymous if you're sending simple octets. Chances are you're not even sending one full `int`, much less three. Unrelated, `&arr` could just be `arr` in the send call. Won't really matter, but still.

Comment: you need `send(sock , &arr,sizeof(arr) , 0);`

Comment: note - in general you need to send a length indicator before the message. TCP is a stream protocol not a message protocol, you cannot expect to receive the same messages tht you send, only the same bytes in  the same order

Comment: unless it is a datagramm mode (udp)

Comment: i did the sizeof(arr) but its still the same

Comment: You need to use `sizeof` in `send` and `recv`.

Comment: oh Thanks Its working now .

Comment: it has to be the length in bytes of the data. Integer is 4 bytes and you have 3 integers to send so it would be 4*3= 12 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

`send()` and `recv()` operate on bytes only.  You are sending and receiving 3 bytes, but your array is actually `sizeof(int) * 3` bytes instead (where `sizeof(int)` is usually 4 on many platforms).  You need to use `sizeof()` on both ends, eg:

```
send(sock, &arr, sizeof(arr), 0);
```

```
recv(new_socket, &arr1, sizeof(arr1), 0);
```

However, you also have to pay attention to return values, because `send()` can send fewer bytes than requested, and `recv()` can receive fewer bytes than requested.  TCP is stream-oriented, not message-oriented. You should be calling `send()` and `recv()` each in a loop, re-calling each one until all expected bytes have been sent/received in full, eg:

```
ssize_t sendAll(int sckt, void *data, size_t length)
{
    char *bytes = (char*) data;
    while (length > 0)
    {
        ssize_t sent = send(sckt, bytes, length, 0);
        if (sent == -1) return -1;
        bytes += sent;
        length -= sent;
    }
    return 0;
}

int arr[3] = {5, 4, 1};
sendAll(sock, &arr, sizeof(arr));
```

```
ssize_t recvAll(int sckt, void *data, size_t length)
{
    char *bytes = (char*) data;
    while (length > 0)
    {
        ssize_t recvd = recv(sckt, bytes, length, 0);
        if (recvd <= 0) return recvd;
        bytes += recvd;
        length -= recvd;
    }
    return 1;
}

int arr1[3];
recvAll(new_socket, &arr1, sizeof(arr1));
```

Comment: also a conversion may be needed if endianness of sender/receiver sides are different

Comment: Seems to be finde. However, I would use `size_t` as type for `length` and `ssize_t` as type for `sent`/`recvd`. It is also a little bit confusing that both functions use different return values. (`sendAll`: 0/OK, -1/IO Error; `recvAll`: 1/OK, 0/Unexpected EOF, -1/IO Error)

Comment: @JojOatXGME many of the standard socket functions return 0 on success and -1 on error, so I followed that same convention for `sendAll()`. Since `recv()` has different semantics, `recvAll()` is similarly different.